# Can I specify a default Color parameter in C# 4.0?

Tags: c#, parameters, c#-4.0, colors, default-value

Here is an example function:

```
public void DrawSquare(int x, int y, Color boxColor = Color.Black)
{
    //Code to draw the square goes here 
}
```

The compiler keeps giving me the error: `Default parameter value for 'boxColor'must be a compile-time constant`

I have tried

```
Color.Black, 
Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Black), and 
Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0)
```

How do I make Color.Black be the default color? Also, I do not want to use a string `Black` to specify it (which I know would work). I want the `Color.Black` value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Color.Black` is a static, not a constant, so no, you cannot do this.

To use a default, you can make the parameter nullable (`Color?`), and if it is null, then set it to Black.

Comment: I had that in my answer, but if you're going to specify a null argument, why not just specify Color.Black? :)

Comment: @George: "Color.Black is a static, not a constant".

Comment: Color is a struct, so if you were to use Nullable<Color> as the type (or in C# Color? for short), then it can be null.

Comment: Indeed, you are explicitly referencing `Color?`, taking my comment back.

Answer (score 18):

Do this:

```
void foo(... Color boxColor = default(Color))
{
   if(object.Equals(boxColor, default(Color))) boxColor = Color.Black;

  // ...
}
```

Quick aside: I like to use `object.Equals` static method because it's a consistent way to write an equality comparison. With reference types such as `string`,  `str.Equals("abc")` can throw NRE, whereas `string.Equals(str, "abc"[,StringComparison.___])` will not. `Color` is a value type and therefore will never be null, but it's better to be consistent in code style, especially at zero additional cost. Obviously this doesn't apply to primitives such as `int` and even `DateTime`, where `==` clearly states/communicates the mathematical equality comparison.

Or, with nullables (credit to Brian Ball's answer):

```
void foo(... Color? boxColor = null)
{
   if(boxColor == null) boxColor = Color.Black;

  // ...
}
```

Comment: why not just `if (boxColor == default(Color))`?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. I prefer the Equals notation, but with value types, the '==' is identical.

Comment: @Mr. TA: well, in this case it could be better to use `Color.Equals` instead of `object.Equals`. Or better `default(Color).Equals(boxColor)` so that you use the virtual function. In my opinion, `==` is more readable, but it's a question of personal taste.

Comment: Maybe it is a performance nad how the algorithm to check for equality, If I not mistaken, I notice the someString == "abc" is not same as someString.Equal("abc") in performance, best practise to use Equal(). Color is value type which mostly == and Equal() produce the same, but for reference type (except string), == and Equal() give much different meaning, == for check the reference equal while the Equal() is depend on the type if the Equal() method overridden.

Comment: @Vlad: there are no virtual functions in value types, and Color.Equals is the same as object.Equals, same as default(Color).Equals(boxColor). The only benefit, IMO, of using object.Equals or Color.Equals over default(Color).Equals(boxColor) is that you are underscoring the fact that you're comparing two values, much in the same way "==" is written - it's a readability issue. Also, for consistency sake, object.Equals(x,y) is better than x.Equals(y) because with reference types, x.Equals(y) can throw NRE, whereas with object.Equals(x,y) you're safe.

Comment: @Mr. TA: (1) Color.Equals is virtual, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e03x8ct2.aspx. (2) `default(Color)` is never `null`. (3) `Color.Equals` is better than `object.Equals`, because the latter can only compare the references (however, it _can_ do the right thing for the value types). More on the topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/09/double-your-dispatch-double-your-fun.aspx

Comment: @Vlad: (1) It's not really virtual, because there's no v-table on a value-type. Secondly, there's no benefit of using object.Equals(x,y) over x.Equals(y) with regards to Equals being virtual or not in the first place. (2) I was referring to code readability and consistency; I said that for reference types, that could be a problem, and hence it's easier to stick to a rule to always use object.Equals(x,y). (3) There's absolutely no difference between object.Equals(x,y) and Color.Equals(x,y), they are one and the same. The links are actually irrelevant to our discussion, but thanks anyways.

Comment: @Mr. TA: (1) in which meaning "not really virtual"? The observable behaviour is that instead of Object.Equals the specific Color.Equals is called. Whether there is or is no vtable is an implementation detail. The behaviour is as of a virtual function, the declaration is as of virtual function, so the function _is_ virtual. You can look up the function `Color.Equals` in Reflector to ensure that does not exactly the same thing as `object.Equals`.

Comment: @Mr. TA: (3) There is a difference, you can check it yourself. The code in `Color.Equals` looks like this: `public override bool Equals(object obj) { if (obj is Color) { Color color = (Color) obj; if (((this.value == color.value) && (this.state == color.state)) && (this.knownColor == color.knownColor)) { return ((this.name == color.name) || (((this.name != null) && (color.name != null)) && this.name.Equals(this.name))); } } return false; }`

Comment: @Vlad: (1) That is correct. But it doesn't change the fact that the correct method is called regardless of calling object.Equals(color1, color2) or color1.Equals(color2). (3) I was referring to the static methods object.Equals(x,y) and Color.Equals(x,y), and you're describing the instance methods object.Equals(y) and Color.Equals(y). My original point was that using the static method object.Equals(x,y) is the best approach across the board, for value types and reference types alike.

Comment: I think @Vlad looks more readable so +1'd as someone else will understand it quickest, and while the virtual function discussion over my head as relative beginner still, I'm assuming any performance saving would not be such big thing...

Answer (score 14):

What's wrong with keeping it simple?

```
public void DrawSquare(int x, int y)
{
    DrawSquare(x,y,Color.Black);
}

public void DrawSquare(int x, int y, Color color)
{
   // Do your thing.
}
```

Comment: The actual function is not that simple. It has around 10 parameters (most of which are optional and can be specified as optional). Plus there are 5 or 6 different functions with these parameters and two variations of each function. To do the above would add way too many functions. Thank you for the suggestion, though.