# C# difference between const int, const someStruct. Why is const someStruct not "compile-time constant"?

Tags: c#, compile-time-constant

```
const Vector4 colorBlack = new Vector4(0,0,0,1);//Vector4 is struct
public static void example(Vector4 color = colorBlack) //not ok
{
   //do something
}
const int someInt = 0;
public static void exampleInt(int n = someInt) // ok
{

}
```

I want know what exactly "compile-time constant" is. From [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485682/c-what-does-compile-time-const-mean) it states

> It just means that every instance of the member marked as const will be replaced with its value during compilation, while readonly members will be resolved at run-time.

So I assumed if I had my colorBlack as const, then it will be compile-time constant, but compiler tells me otherwise. 
But it doesn't complain about "const int some int = 0;" being compile-time constant.

Why?

Comment: What does the compiler say?

Comment: @deviantfan Default parameter value for 'color' must be a compile-time constant

Comment: How compiler could possibly know the value of colorBlack in compile time? You need to run Vector4 constructor to find it's value.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly but shouldn't having "const" make it to call the constructor during compile time? That's what the answer said " member marked as const will be replaced with its value during compilation" Then I suppose the answer from my reading is wrong?

Comment: Compilator can't run the program. The code can be run only when you start you program. You can read more about it in `CLR via C#` by J.Richter

Comment: sweet book oh man I did not know such book exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Can I specify a default Color parameter in C# 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454336/can-i-specify-a-default-color-parameter-in-c-sharp-4-0)

Also: [Default arguments for structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676128/default-arguments-for-structures)

As described in [Section 7.15](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691319(v=vs.71).aspx), a constant-expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile-time. Since the only way to create a non-null value of a reference-type other than string is to apply the new operator, and since the new operator is not permitted in a constant-expression, the only possible value for constants of reference-types other than string is null.

In other words, at compile time, you can only default to:

- null
- a literal string
- new T() // no arguments, or equivalently default(T)

Since you can only use new if you are using default arguments, and you can't do that with a reference type (struct) and because you need to specify some specific arguments anyway, you're only option is to pass null.

```
const Vector4 colorBlack = new Vector4(0,0,0,1);  // Vector4 is struct
public static void example(Vector4? color = null) // ? makes it nullable
{
    if (color == null)
        color = colorBlack;
}
```

Comment: So I can't have constant expression of values other than ones listed in the section,string and null. Then what does having const in front of variable colorBlack mean? the keyword is supposed to make the variable "const" but from what I read having "const" in front of the variable is supposed to be impossible?

Comment: @BlueBug there are two ways to create a constant field. `const` and `readonly`

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly Can I understand it as, I can create constant field but they won't necessarily be "compile time constant"? **BUT** doesn't const make the variable to be replaced with value during compile time?

Comment: If you use boxing, or just convert your struct to a class, in otherwords make it nullable, then you can just use = null as the default, and then check for that int he function and assign it to colorBlack.